# Python output beautifier subprocess

Tags: python

Hello i am using `subprocess`.

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(['ls'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = proc.stdout.read()
print(output)
```

output  is correct

```
b'file.txt\nmain.py\nsource\ntest-page\n'
```

is there any way  to beautify it , like in linux server ?

```
root@master:/home/python# ls
file.txt  main.py  source  test-page
```

Comment: Do you mean to make it on a single line? with spacing in between? why don't you just replace the `\n` with `  ` (the two spaces) in your example?

Comment: yep , i try but not working , can you show your example /

Comment: `ls` is a poor example for many reasons; it detects when it's not connected to a terminal, and changes its output format. There's [a large number of other reasons to avoid `ls` in scripts.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) Anyway, Python already knows how to list files; examine `os.scandir()` and friends.

Answer (score 0):

Use `split()` by newline to get the files, then print each on a separate line:

```
lines = output.split(b'\n')

for line in lines:
    print(line.decode())
```

prints each file on a separate line:

```
file.txt  
main.py  
source  
test-page
```

Comment: Thanks but i do not want newline , my purpose is like in real terminal output in one line

Comment: Use `lines = output.decode().split('\n')` and 
`output_str = ' '.join(lines)` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
print(output.decode().rstrip().replace("\n", " " * 2))
```

```
file.txt   main.py   source   test-page
```

- `decode()` is to convert bytes to string
- `rstrip()` removes the last trailing `"\n"`, but this is optional
- `replace("\n", " " * 2))` will replace `"\n"` (newline character) into 2 spaces

Answer (score 0):

#### Background on vertical format used by `ls`

Terminal uses space-separated columnar output, see [GNU docs on `ls`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/General-output-formatting.html):

> **`‘--format=vertical’`**
>
> List files in columns, sorted vertically, with no other information. This is the default for `ls` if standard output is a terminal. It is always the default for the `dir` program. GNU `ls` uses **variable width columns** to display as many files as possible in the fewest lines.

(added emphasis in bold)

This means depending on the longest filename the column-width is adjusted and number of columns can vary. But it uses 2 spaces between the columns.

#### Simple

A simple two-spaces separation could be achieved by [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20replace#str.replace).

```
output = b'file.txt\nmain.py\nsource\ntest-page'
vertical = output.decode().replace('\n', ' ' * 2)
print(vertical)
```

Prints:

```
file.txt  main.py  source  test-page
```

#### Columnar

Some advanced library can do the trick, e.g. [columnar](https://pypi.org/project/columnar/).